# My Wamp Server Crashes when i Launch it

Tags: wamp, runtime-error, wampserver, windows-server-2012

When I starts my WAMP server it shows

> Run Time error 216 at 004038A6.

When I try to re-install the same thing happens (from windows control panel also). I am using Windows Server 2012 trial version. WAMP was working perfectly till I last shut down my system.

What could be the reason for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was a Trojan attack. I had to fix the problem by Re-installing my windows.